# Rails link_to existing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to link to an action in my controller from a view. When I rake routes, I see

```
document_version_file_index GET    /document_versions/:document_version_id/file(.:format)           file#index
```

I think that's the route I want to hit. My controller is called document_versions_controller and it includes an action called download that I want to call. When I try

```
<%= link_to linkText, :document_version_file  %>
```

I get a routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"files"}
```

There is no files controller. I'm trying to hit the document_version controller. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
How I am building my route:

```
resources :document_versions do
    resources :files
    member do 
      get 'download', :action => :download
      resources :document_version
    end
  end
```

EDIT 2:
Can we step back and pretend I don't have a route in existence already? I have a view and a controller. The controller has `def download`, is named `document_versions_controller.rb` and has `class DocumentVersionsController < ApplicationController`. How can I make a route that hits that download method and call it with a link click in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was conflating two goals: building a route to hit my controller action, and building my api call url. The api url (which includes `file` and `version_id`) is being built in the controller action, and it is incorrect to try to build a route to match the api url. I modified my routes.rb so now it looks like this:

```
 resources :document_versions do
    member do 
      get 'download', :action => :download
    end
  end
```

and my link_to in the view looks like this:

```
<%= link_to linkText, download_api_document_versions_path(:version_id => version.document_version[:id]) %>
```

and my controller performs an api call with Faraday in the download action.

Comment: Glad you found the problem here!

Answer (score 3):

That route requires a `:document_version_id` argument, so you can't call it straight-up like that. The way to use that route would be:

```
document_version_file_index_path(@document_version_file)
```

I'm not sure why the route has `index` in the name, normally automatically generated routes don't.

The easy way to remember how those routes work is for every `:x` type argument in the path that's not optional, not inside brackets, you provide the value for that in the call in the order they appear.

A route to `/:a/:b.(:c)` can be called as `x(a,b)` or `x(a,b,c)`, either way is valid, as `:c` is optional.

Comment: Sorry, it's not automatically generated, I think. I added this to routes.rb: `resources :document_versions do
    resources :files
    collection do 
      get 'download', :action => :download
      resources :document_version
    end
  end `

Comment: In this answer, @document_version_file should be the :document_version_id value? When I try that I get `syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: Use `member do`(this is on an instance) instead of `collection do`(this is on a class) and then use what `rake routes` spits out

Comment: You need some kind of ID here, so pass through a model that contains one, or the raw value if that's all you have handy, as in it's coming in via a `param`. If you're getting a syntax error on a bracket you're doing something odd. For chunks of code like that, just edit and add that to your question where the formatting is easier to manage.

Comment: Both `@document_version_file` or `@document_version_file.id` will work. Most people say use `@document_version_file`

Comment: @SirBertly You should never call `id` on a model when adding it to a route. The correct method is `to_param`, but that's called for you automatically so it's best omitted. A model can override what it's URL-based "id" is, that's what `to_param` is for, so force-calling `id` can introduce nasty bugs.

Comment: I changed the routes.rb to have `member do` and my route is now changed to `document_version_files`. I still get the syntax error when I try to `link_to linkText, :document_version_files(version.document_version.id)`

Comment: should this move to chat?

Comment: Use the object as @tadman says above. Also, you're messing up your symbols and your strings. Try document_version_files_path(object). No semi-colon

Comment: when I do as @tadman suggested, I get `undefined method `document_version_file_index_path'`

Comment: rake routes includes `document_version_files GET    /document_versions/:document_version_id/files(.:format)     document_versions#index` I think that's the one I'm trying to hit, but I want it to hit the download action in that controller.

Comment: The name of the route helper method is always the first part plus `_path`, so in this case `document_version_files_path`.

Comment: the link looks correct to me now, but when I click it, it says `uninitialized constant DocumentVersionsController`

Comment: Are your file and class named correctly? `class DocumentVersionsController < ApplicationController`

Comment: potentially not named correctly: `class Api::DocumentVersionsController < ApplicationController` but I removed the `Api::` to test this and I still get the same error.

Comment: figured out some problems with how I had it set up and posted as an answer. Thanks for the help and apologies for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
<%= link_to linkText, :document_version_file_index_path(@document_version_file)  %>
```

Where `@document_version_file` is the document version of which you want to see all the files.

Edited:
This will give the routes as your exceptions.

```
get 'document_versions/:document_version_id/files' => 'document_versions#index', as: : document_version_files
```